# SwiftUI backgroundTask

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, combine

Hello I want to achieve to execute the publisher after app entered the background mode.

I have backgroundTask defined like this

```
    .backgroundTask(.appRefresh("asyncTaskId")) { sendable in
        await viewModel.asyncTask()
    }
```

After app enters the background scene this code get executed

```
    let request = BGProcessingTaskRequest(identifier: "asyncTaskId")
    request.requiresNetworkConnectivity = true
    request.requiresExternalPower = false
    do {
        try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
    } catch {

    }
```

And after submit I call

```
e -l objc -- (void)[[BGTaskScheduler sharedScheduler] _simulateLaunchForTaskWithIdentifier:@"asyncTaskId"]
```

Everythin works well and function gets called. Inside the asyncTask there is Sequence of publishers with collect() at the end like this :

```
        Publishers.Sequence(sequence: publishers)
        .flatMap(maxPublishers: .max(1), {$0})
        .collect()
        .sink....
        .store...
```

While in foreground function does what I want. But called from background mode the publisher sink gets never executed sometimes when I put debug points it gets there but without it looks like it created publisher probably even fired execute of publisher but response is not getting there.
Can It be delayed and i get response after hour?

console says:

```
2023-11-23 10:07:52.770960+0100  Simulating launch for task with identifier asyncTaskId
2023-11-23 10:08:02.028939+0100  [userFlow] Submit asyncTask:
2023-11-23 10:08:02.033054+0100  Starting simulated task: <decode: missing data>
2023-11-23 10:08:02.070868+0100  [userFlow] BGAppRefreshTaskRequest received - run asyncTask:
```

EDIT:
After reopening the app from background I got the body of publisher executed and console printed out

```
2023-11-23 10:20:22.691887+0100 Marking simulated task complete: <BGProcessingTask: asyncTask>
```

Comment: Publishers aren't compatible with `async/await` if you don't compensate for that the task will be closed long before the publishers return. `asyncTask` should be fully compatible with `async/await`